# Putting a windowsformhost inside a usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, windowsformshost

I'm trying to put a windowsformshost inside a WPF UserControl.   Whenever I shrink the size of the UserControl the windowsformshost seems bleed out of the UserControl?   Is there anyway to make the windowsformshost stay inside the usercontrol?   I saw some examples online but none of them work.  I am putting the windowsformshost inside a grid.   Is there someplace else I have to place it?   Thank you in advance for the help.

David

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `WindowsFormHost` always have width and height like your parent control, you can

1) Put it to the `DockPanel` with `LastChildFill="True"`

2) Bind to the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of your parent control (either `Grid` or `UserControl`) with the width and height of your `WindowFormHost`.